# Vagrant, homestead ip addresses Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, homestead

It is a beginner's question, and if someone could explain the whole IP address confusion that I have at the moment with Vagrant box, I would be very thankful. In the documentation it says, that we must add the "domains" for our Nginx sites to the hosts file on our machine.

```
192.168.10.10  homestead.app
```

Is that Nginx ip address, then?
Then later, it says, that we can access our DB on:

```
127.0.0.1:33060 (MySql)
127.0.0.1:54320 (Postgres)
```

Then how it is suppose to look the .env file?

```
DB_HOST=192.168.10.10 or
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

The whole concept of homestead, vagrant and web server and DB in it is a bit vague, so some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=your_db
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

`192.168.10.10` is an address you use on your host machine to access web server on a guest machine (Homestead).

`127.0.0.1` is a `localhost`. PHP on a quest machine uses it to access MySQL hosted on a same machine.

Comment: And that is then also the address of Nginx web server, that is running on Homestead machine, right?

Comment: So Homestead access it's own machine on 127.0.0.1 to access the DB, right? Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: But in my .env file I have DB_HOST as 192.168.10.10 and I am not sure but from what I remember Sequel Pro was configured to connect to the DB on 127.0.0.1? Is that possible, because as it is now, everything works.

Comment: It works too, but still it's a good practice to use 127.0.0.1.

Comment: And that is the confusing part to me, if Sequel Pro is on a local machine, how is it connecting to the DB on Homestead machine with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I am actually connecting with Sequel Pro on 192.168.10.10 so it all makes sense now! :)

Comment: But, I guess I wouldn't be able to connect at all with Sequel Pro if I had 127.0.0.1 as an address in standard connection there. Because, from what you sad @Alexey Mezenin, I understood that we should connect to Homestead with that address, and then if we need to connect from Homestead to DB we can use 127.0.0.1. Correct me if I am wrong!